# Test if a value exists in $form_state

Tags: 8

If I wanted to rebuild a form in Drupal 7, conditional on the state of the form, I would do something like this:

```
if (isset($form_state['values']['foo'])) {
  $form['...
}
```

Now, `$form_state` is an object in Drupal 8. What would be the best equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much `$form_state->getValue('foo');`.

[See the docs page for getValue](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormStateInterface.php/function/FormStateInterface%3A%3AgetValue/8.4.x).

Answer (score 1):

I belive that the equivalent to `isset()` is

```
if ($form_state->hasValue('foo')) {
  ...
}
```